# How to convert every page in a XPS file to an image in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xps

Is there a way to convert every page in a XPS document to an image programmatically using C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran across this blog post from [Josh Twist](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Josh.aspx) that appears to do what you want.

[Cracking an XPS in WPF](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Cracking_an_XPS_in_WPF.aspx)

On searching the net, there are many paid/trial programs that claim to do this (I have not tried any of them, so I can't vouch/list any of them).  I assumed you want to write your own code.

Here is the 'meat' of the blog post (condensed):

```
Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("memorystream://{0}", "file.xps"));
FixedDocumentSequence seq;

using (Package pack = Package.Open("file.xps", ...))
using (StorePackage(uri, pack))  // see method below
using (XpsDocument xps = new XpsDocument(pack, Normal, uri.ToString()))
{
    seq = xps.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
}

DocumentPaginator paginator = seq.DocumentPaginator;
Visual visual = paginator.GetPage(0).Visual;  // first page - loop for all

FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)visual;

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)fe.ActualWidth,
                          (int)fe.ActualHeight, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
bmp.Render(fe);

PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

using (Stream stream = File.Create("file.png"))
{
    png.Save(stream);
}

public static IDisposable StorePackage(Uri uri, Package package)
{
    PackageStore.AddPackage(uri, package);
    return new Disposer(() => PackageStore.RemovePackage(uri));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! This is exactly what I'v wanted; and I have used it and it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for this solution. You would think that a relatively straightforward operation would be a lot easier than this fairly dense code... its not exactly obvious.

Comment: The package store stuff isn't necessary if the document is on disk.  Just create an XpsDocument using the constructor overload that takes a file path, then skip to `GetFixedDocumentSequence()` and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795996/4390133) it is really helpful (it helped me also) .I just want to note to some very important point in that solution.

if you are implementing your own [DocumentPaginator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpaginator(v=vs.110).aspx) (as in my case) then that code will Not work because we will not get reference to your specific Paginator from the statement

```
DocumentPaginator paginator = seq.DocumentPaginator;
```

Casting this to your own paginator also will not work.

also that solution is very complex in case you have your own `Paginator`. 
So I developed a simplified solution , which based on the accepted solution of this question and this worked exactly as needed.

```
 // create your own paginator instead of this
 // this is my specific own implementation for DocumentPaginator class
 ReportPaginator paginator = new ReportPaginator(report);

 Visual visual = paginator.GetPage(0).Visual;  // first page - loop for all

 RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)paginator.PageSize.Width, (int)paginator.PageSize.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
 bmp.Render(visual);

 PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
 png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

 using (MemoryStream sm = new MemoryStream())
 {
     png.Save(sm);
     return sm.ToArray();
 }
```